# In the context of year values how does "aaaa" differ from "yyyy"?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Referring to the [SimpleDateFormat docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), the pattern character for representing years is `y`, so we have representations like `yy` and `yyyy` (13, 2013 respectively). That's fine.

When I output the `DEFAULT` / `SHORT` / `MEDIUM` / `LONG` / `FULL` patterns for most locales, I get something along these lines:

(EG: New Zealand)

```
Default: d/MM/yyyy
Short: d/MM/yy
Medium: d/MM/yyyy
Long: d MMMM yyyy
Full: EEEE, d MMMM yyyy
```

However looking at some locales, eg France, I get this:

```
Default: j MMM aaaa
Short: jj/MM/aa
Medium: j MMM aaaa
Long: j MMMM aaaa
Full: EEEE j MMMM aaaa
```

Obviously here `aaaa` is a representation of the year, but what's the distinction in intent between `yyyy` and `aaaa`? IE: why do they use `aaaa` instead of just `yyyy`.

Initially I thought it might be something along the lines of French for "[y]ear" is "[a]nnée" (and "[d]ay" is "[j]our", but I see it's also `aaaa` for Hungarian (and many other locales), and Hungarian for "year" is "év" (day "nap"), so I think the "a" / "année" correlation I'm making is coincidence.

So what is the difference one is supposed to infer here?

I googled about, but drew a blank. Also it might be as obvious as an obvious thing to a Java dev, but I'm just a CFML dev who simply bolts Java into my CFML occasionally when Java does something more expediently than I can do it in native CFML. So sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: I had no idea that the format is displayed in a localized form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `java.text.DateFormatSymbols` you'll find the following field:

```
/**
 * Localized date-time pattern characters. For example, a locale may
 * wish to use 'u' rather than 'y' to represent years in its date format
 * pattern strings.
 * This string must be exactly 18 characters long, with the index of
 * the characters described by <code>DateFormat.ERA_FIELD</code>,
 * <code>DateFormat.YEAR_FIELD</code>, etc.  Thus, if the string were
 * "Xz...", then localized patterns would use 'X' for era and 'z' for year.
 * @serial
 */
String  localPatternChars = null;
```

This is a string containing a character for each format element in a predefined order (E.g., character 0 is the Era format character, character 1 is the Year format character, etc).

This field is loaded from the `sun.text.resources.FormatData` resource bundle (per locale, of course), from the `DateTimePatternChars` key.

If you examine the `sun.text.resources.FormatData_fr` resource, you'll find the key-value pair `{ "DateTimePatternChars", "GaMjkHmsSEDFwWxhKzZ" }`.

To make a long story short - the "a" format character in France locale has the **exact** same effect as the "y" format character in US locale, it's just called differently.

Comment: Cheers, that all makes sense.