# What are the guarantees of DateFormatSymbols.getLocalPatternChars()?

Tags: java, datetime, localization

While investigating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594519/how-do-i-get-localized-date-pattern-string) I stumbled upon [DateFormatSymbols.getLocalPatternChars()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getLocalPatternChars%28%29). The javadoc just says

> Gets localized date-time pattern characters. For example: 'u', 't', etc.

So I was wondering how any use of this method can be made, if there is no guarantee about the returned string. For example it could return the pattern chars in decreasing order, era to second for example (as it seems to currently do in oracle JVM, see implementation of `SimpleDateFormat`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pointed to the answer by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154502/1466267) to another question.

The answer is found in the javadoc of  `java.text.DateFormatSymbols.localPatternChars`:

> Localized date-time pattern characters. For example, a locale may wish
>   to use 'u' rather than 'y' to represent years in its date format
>   pattern strings. This string must be exactly 18 characters long, with
>   the index of the characters described by
>   `DateFormat.ERA_FIELD`, `DateFormat.YEAR_FIELD`,
>   etc.  Thus, if the string were "Xz...", then localized patterns would
>   use 'X' for era and 'z' for year.

But since those guarantees are only an implemetnation detail for oracle JVM, they could not be portable.